# Xamarin Forms - check if files exist in Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

In Xamarin Forms, how can we check if Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory contains files or not?

I'm using the following to download images from azure storage and show them on the page, it works fine but I only want to do that if no files exist.

```
_activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            var imgPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "");
            var blobList = await BlobStorageService.GetBlobs<CloudBlockBlob>("images");

            foreach (CloudBlockBlob b in blobList)
            {
                Image _image = new Image();
                imgPath = imgPath + b.Name;
                await b.DownloadToFileAsync(imgPath, FileMode.Create);

                StackLayout s = new StackLayout();
                _title.Text = b.Name;
                _image.Source = imgPath; 
                s.Children.Add(_title);
                s.Children.Add(_image);
                iStack.Children.Add(s);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check files exist or not using this :

```
 if (File.Exists(imgPath))
        {
           **Write Your Code**
        }
```